# Is there a way to list records by created_at DESC but only for current and past dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, sql-order-by

I have a Ruby on Rails application that allows for users to create a `Box` (gym) and then create `Workouts` so that users can see what they will be doing that day.

```
Box has_many :workouts
Workout belongs_to :box
```

I have given the user the ability to edit the workout.created_at field and allow them to enter workouts for future dates. On the /view/boxes/show.html.erb page, I only want to display Workouts that are for the present date and in the past. So essentially I want to list all workouts by `created_at DESC` but I don't want future Workouts. Is there a way to do this in the controller action?

```
@workouts = @box.workouts.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
```

If not, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to add in the additional conditions to only return the 'past' records:

```
@workouts = @box.workouts.all(:order => "created_at DESC", :conditions => ["created_at <= ?", Time.now])
```

That should show all workouts for a given box, but only those that were created today or in the past.